# Abstraction of class methods interaction with database not working,

Tags: php, mysql, abstraction

I have a class called user. I am trying to make some of the usual database methods abstract so I can shift all these functions into a database 'super object'.

```
    class User {

        protected static $table_name="users";
        protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'first_name');

        public $id;
        public $first_name;


    public function create() {
    global $database;
    $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
    $sql .= "')";
    if($database->query($sql)) {
    $this->id = $database->insert_id();
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
   }
  }
```

This is what I have done to my create method to make it class agnostic. As you can see, its really simple - just two database fields first name and id. The id is set to not NULL and autoincrement. My problem is this......

The $database->insert_id() method simply pulls the last id created in the database over this connection.

If I run a simple create as follows

```
 $user = new User();
 $user->first_name = "Paul";
 $user->create();
```

I get...

```
 Database query failed: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

 Last SQL query: INSERT INTO test_user (id, first_name) VALUES ('', 'Paul')
```

The $sql statement is correct as far as I can see. I understand that the issue is with the ID not being set but if its set as auto increment shouldn't this be automatically set.....

Also...I know that PDO is the way to go but for now (and I am incrementally learning it), could someone help me with this...

Comment: SQL is not PHP, while '' evaluates to null in PHP, it doesn't in SQL. In SQL it's an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Customised the function create. This will work for the above scenario.

```
public function create()  { 

    global $database;

    foreach($this->sanitized_attributes() as $key=>$attribute) {
        if ((is_null($attribute)) || empty($attribute)) {
            $attributes[$key] = "null";
        } else {
            $attributes[$key] = "'" . $attribute . "'";
        }
    } 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= ") VALUES (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_values($attributes));
    $sql .= ")";
    if($database->query($sql)) {
    $this->id = $database->insert_id();
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```